# List of random numbers and find 5 equal blocks to assign numbers 1 - 5

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a list of frequencies for incidents.  I want to assign a value of 1 - 5 to a column next to the frequencies from Top 20% and then the next 20% and so on to 0.  So this is 5 equal sets of buckets essentially.

I have tried rank but cant seem to get anything to work.  I would like to keep this in sheets but can use excel.

```
55
66
12
12
22
2
7
1
7
1
3
4
25
1
1
2
1
2
15
3
1
1
1
2
3
6
1
1
1
8
2
4
5
2
9
3
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
2
1
4
3
1
1
1
1
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
2
1
1
1
1
3
1
1
2
2
1
2
1
3
2
1
4
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
9
2
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
2
2
1
3
1
1
1
7
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
1
3
2
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
6
1
2
2
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
2
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
3
1
1
2
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
4
1
7
7
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
7
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
4
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
4
3
1
3
1
5
1
2
1
3
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
6
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
6
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
4
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Would like to get this to work in sheets and when I add another row of data it will alter the list to make sure they are all still in the correct buckets.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information), and include an example showing a successful outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-x_5c_Z2RlQVDCFMPJoapoyvTBI11t3bhax60Pw29M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So i made a new spreadsheet.  This shows the data that I want to have.  Then a chart to show what numbers I want to assign to the column next to it.

Comment: is this solved already? if not can you provide an example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

Billy,

Not too sure how exactly this is formatted. I assume that each number you posted is a datapoint in your list. If i understand correctly, you need to do the following.

1) You can use the `percentrank` function in each cell next to the incident frequency datapoint like. `=percentrank(datarange,datapoint,significant figures)` where datarange is the whole range of your data (make sure to use an absolute range with $) and datapoint is the cell reference. Since google sheets doesn't have tables that autofill formulae like Excel, you'll have to manually slide down the `percentrank` function every time you add a new row.

Comment: I have shared a spreadsheet above and a chart on what I want to achieve.  The top 20 percent get a rating of 5. Then the next 20 percent gets a rating of 4 and so on down to 1.

Comment: Ok, that's what i figured. I did the edit in your spreadsheet (sorry lol). Using this function `=if(percentrank(B$3:B$700,B6,4)>=0.8,5,if(percentrank(B$3:B$700,B6,4)>=0.6,4,if(percentrank(B$3:B$700,B6,4)>=0.4,3,if(percentrank(B$3:B$700,B6,4)>=0.2,2,1))))`
It's rather inelegant, but straightforward and get the job done. You'll need to update the range `B$3:B$700` as the sheet grows, but otherwise it's functional.

Comment: Just noticed that since you have so many occurrences of "1", anything greater than 1 pretty much flags as a "rating 5". We'll either need to not use even quintiles (80% of occurrences are just 1) or base ratings on the actual value (e.g. 1 =1, 2 through 5 = 2, 6 through 15 =3, etc)

Comment: That works great but I have added in text from what else I am trying to achieve in the sheets document.  I don't know if this formula works with that.

Example:  
If the total frequencies for all issues summed together was 10000
Each segment (1-5) is worth 2000
The score of 5 is assigned to the top defects where the       combined frequencies add up to 2000.
Similarly, the score 4 is assigned to the next group of defects    where the combined frequencies add up to 2000.